# How to use 31.0 Api Version

Tags: api, soap-api, metadata-api

i have a developer org in which i can set highest version upto 30.0 .but there is a lot of upgrades in 31.0 metadata api.How can i use 31.0 api version in my apex class and pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check Salesforce Scheduled Release:
https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/

You have to wait until your organization is upgraded to summer 14.