# Invalid Api Version specified on URL-Cannot create Eclipse Force.com IDE Project

Tags: eclipse

Users who are facing this issue while creating project using Luna Release (4.4.0) or any other version of Eclipse, follow the below link to address this issue.

1. Check what version of Force.com API is installed ? 
   How do I check this ? 
   Click Help-> Installation Details: Your API version should look something like this Force.com IDE    31.X.X...
2. Uninstall this Force.com API.
   How do I uninstall ? 
   Help-> Install New Software: Click on "Available Software Site". You should see Force.com software installed. Select Force.com and Click on "Remove" button. 
   Restart eclipse. If you still see this software, Just extract eclipse again.
3. Install Force.com API using : http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42
   Before moving to next step, 
   uncheck : [image]

Now you should see : [image]

Select Version Force.com IDE 30.0XXXX
Continue with installation, and you should be good.

Comment: Hepled me, solution is spot on

Comment: Hi Srinath welcome to stackexchange .So i would request you to post question and if you intend to self answer there click on answer and answer the same .I understand that you may not have sufficient reputation to start answering but wait till you have and then you can answer the same .

Comment: As Mohith says, can you suggest an edit for this to make it into a question, and then post the answer below?

Comment: Please check this link:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42399/how-to-use-31-0-api-version/42401#42401